# rewriting sync as async: not wait on a func

Tags: python, asynchronous, sanic

As I read more, I feel more stupid about aysnc in python. So I decided to ask for a direct answer. How can I change the following code (using async or similar approaches) to achieve the desired result? Additionally, how can I do it in flask or sanic?

```py
import time

def long_job():
    print('long job started')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('long job ended')

def main_job():
    long_job()
    time.sleep(1)
    print('main job returned')

main_job()

# expected result:
# 'long job started'
# 'main job returned'
# 'long job ended'
```

Basically, I **do NOT want** to await for long_job to end before returning my main_job. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Advance thanks doesn't help my rep score any :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Await asyncio's `sleep()` to yield time to other jobs (if you don't need to await something else).
Use `create_task()` instead of `await` to start a job without blocking.
Finally, you have to start the main job using the event loop.

```
# Written in Python 3.7
import asyncio

async def long_job():
    print('long job started')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('long job ended')

async def main_job():
    asyncio.create_task(long_job())
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('main job returned')
```

Your framework should start the event loop; you don't have to start it yourself. You can `await` or call `create_task` on `main_job()` from an `async def` function called by your framework, depending on if you want to block or not.

---

If you want to test this without a framework, you'll have to start the loop yourself using `asyncio.run()`. This will stop immediately after its task completes, even if other tasks haven't finished yet. But this is easy enough to work around:

```
async def loop_job():
    asyncio.create_task(main_job())
    while len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()) > 1:  # Any task besides loop_job()?
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)

asyncio.run(loop_job())
```

If you're implementing a framework yourself, you can use the more primitive `loop.run_forever()`, but you'd have to `stop()` it yourself.

Comment: It seems Sanic does the loop job :) Thanks :)

Comment: @gilch Nice explanation !

Comment: for python 3.6 you have to do like this 
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() 
task1 = loop.create_task(main_job())